# How to load vue components from remote server (backend)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, vite

I have backend on Nest.js, which store components source code, and links between users (domain name from Referer header) and components. So, different users should use own set of components.

I have frontend on Vue.js which build with vite.
My frontend do `import("https://example.com/api/component").then(...)` to import components from remote server (dependent on Referer header). But, in remote component's I haven't access to Vue app instance (ex: I can't do `import { computed } from "vue"` or import other components bundled in main application).
How to solve this problem and is it possible at all? Thank you